The use of the definite article with the word "future"
What is the difference between these two phrases - "in future" and "in the future"? I am specifically interested in the first phrase, without any article. In what circumstances is it used, please?

This question is similar to: Usage of word "In future" or "In the future". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Which phrase should be used, in future or in the future? and At some point "in future" or "in the future", among others.

In future is very commonly used to mean from now on. Cambridge Dictionary gives some examples.
In the future can be used to speak of things that are predicted to happen at some unspecified time. In the future, humans may be able to live on the Moon.

Thanks, Kate. Taking into account the definition for "in future" given by CD "used at the beginning or end of a sentence in which there is a decision about a plan of action or a warning", can I then say " I am planning to travel to the sea in future"? It's my decision. Though with "in future" the sentence sound awkward, if I am honest.

That would imply that you intend to take all your holidays (vacations) at the seaside from now on!

I'll wash the dishes in future means From now on, I'll [always] do the dish-washing. Note that I'll wash the dishes in the future isn't very idiomatic, but what it means is I'll wash the dishes later (a "one-off" activity that I don't want to do now)
